# Activity's TextView is null

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, textview, retrofit

I'm trying to make an app to check the weather using `OpenWeatherMap`, `Kotlin`, `Retrofit`, and `MVP` with [the clean architecture](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

The app is very simple, has only one activity and the layout shows different data according to the location that the user selects. When initiating the activity, this initializes the presenter in `onCreate` and calls the method that initiates the request process. When I return to my activity with the answer, I am trying to show some information about that response in a `TextView`, but the app crashes because that view is `null`.

I'm using `Kotlin Android Extensions`, which allows me, theoretically, to invoke the view only with its id, without needing to use `findViewById`.

I'm new to Kotlin and maybe I'm missing something.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.climaconsulta.R
import com.climaconsulta.user.model.pojos.MainWeather
import com.climaconsulta.user.presenter.MainActivityPresenter
import com.climaconsulta.user.presenter.MainActivityPresenterImpl
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MainActivityView {
    var presenter: MainActivityPresenter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        presenter = MainActivityPresenterImpl()
        presenter!!.getMainWeather("London")
    }

    override fun showCurrentCity() {
        presenter!!.getCurrentCity()
    }

    override fun showMainWeather(mainWeather: MainWeather) {
        mainTemperature.text = mainWeather.main!!.temp.toString()
        // HERE I TRY TO SET THE TEXT. BUT "mainTemperature" IS NULL
    }

    override fun showFiveDaysWeather(cityName: String) {
        presenter!!.getFiveDaysWheather(cityName)
    }

    override fun showError(error: String) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your imports

Comment: Sorry... Imports added!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, why you **force** nullable type to run itself? Why you do not call it in a safe way like this `presenter?.func()`? **Force** call will crash your app but **safe** call - not.

Secondly, move these lines below into `onStart()`

```
presenter = MainActivityPresenterImpl()
presenter?.getMainWeather("London")
```

> I would like to recommend you to use in presenter `MainActivityView`
>   interface that implements your MainActivity. I do not see when you set
>   it into `presenter`.

Example -->

**BasePresenter:**

```
abstract class BasePresenter<View : BaseView> {
    protected var view: View? = null

    open fun attachView(view: View) {
        this.view = view
    }

    open fun detachView(view: View) {
        if (this.view == view) {
            this.view = null
        }
    }
}

interface BaseView {
    fun showError(error: String)
}
```

**Presenter:**

```
class MainPresenter() : BasePresenter<MainActivityView>() {
    private fun getMainWeather(name: String) {
        view?.showProgress(true)
        ...
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
@Inject
protected lateinit var presenter: MainPresenter
...

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    presenter.attachView(this)
}

override fun onStop() {
    presenter.detachView(this)
    super.onStop()
}
```

And yes, I use **Dagger 2** to provide dependencies. You may use it as I sad:

```
presenter = MainActivityPresenterImpl()
presenter?.getMainWeather("London")
```

But if you want you may look at simple [Dagger 2 implementation](https://github.com/yaroslav-android/FetchPublicGitHubRepos) for a small project.

Comment: Does not work .. I get data. I mean, weather data is coming to my activity. But the view still null. Thank you about the info about safe call. I was using !! just because I believed that was the correct way. But after your answer, I read about it.